# Dummy/test truffle contract?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I am having trouble migrating a contract using truffle.  So I want to test with another contract.  I know nothing about this.

Can someone point me to a contract/project I can download and migrate?  I'm using a private blockchain, so amount of gas is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project deploys two contracts, one fairly small and one fairly big:
https://github.com/realitykeys/realitycheck

```
cd truffle
truffle migrate --reset
```

The HTML/JS app build is handled separately, so all `truffle migrate` does is compile and deploy contracts and save their details.

Comment: Thank you.  That completely failed.  And that is what I expected. :)  It means that the problem with my other contract is not a problem with the contract.  I still have gas limit problems.  Man, I wish someone knew something about that.  I'd happily pay if I could get that working.